# Django ImageField / FileField custom upload_to function, and security

Tags: django, security, path, filefield

I have part of a model defined like this:

```
logo_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=lambda i, fn: "logo_%s"%(fn), height_field="logo_image_height", width_field="logo_image_width")
```

and had a question about the upload_to function.

According to [django's documentation for FileField.upload_to](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), the second paramater, `filename` is "The filename that was originally given to the file."

Now, knowing about HTTP, file uploads, etc, the end user's client can easily fake the filename. In particular, couldn't the end client upload a file called "/etc/passwd", for example, and then if I use my naive code (`lambda i, fn: "logo_%s"%(fn)`), wouldn't the resulting file be uploaded to `/etc/passwd`? Do I need to escape the `filename` parameter?

```
#using django's example of using full paths in settings module,
#MEDIA_ROOT="/tmp/media"
>>> os.path.join("/tmp/media/", "apple.jpg")
'/tmp/media/apple.jpg'
>>> os.path.join("/tmp/media/", "/etc/passwd")
'/etc/passwd'
```

Thanks for any suggestions / answers / clarification.

## Edit

The important methods to look at are [in files.py, near line 272](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L272):

```
272         def get_directory_name(self):
273             return os.path.normpath(force_unicode(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(smart_str(self.upload_to))))
274     
275         def get_filename(self, filename):
276             return os.path.normpath(self.storage.get_valid_name(os.path.basename(filename)))
277     
278         def generate_filename(self, instance, filename):
279             return os.path.join(self.get_directory_name(), self.get_filename(filename))
```

Defining a custom `upload_to` replaces `generate_filename`() as seen [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L225):

```
226             if callable(upload_to):
227                 self.generate_filename = upload_to
```

Then, in the [save() method](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L89):

```
89      def save(self, name, content, save=True):
90          name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
91          self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
```

And the returned filename is passed to the storage class which eventually calls a django replacement function in the _os.py util module [safe_join](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/_os.py#L24).

That function appears to alleviate my fears:

```
24    def safe_join(base, *paths):
25      """
26      Joins one or more path components to the base path component intelligently.
27      Returns a normalized, absolute version of the final path.
28  
29      The final path must be located inside of the base path component (otherwise
30      a ValueError is raised).
31      """
```

Comment: So... you don't really need this question answered then?

Comment: Sorry :) Appears not. Just looking for verification (somebody doing another look though) at this point.

Comment: It might be clearer if you "answer your own question" and then mark it as answered so it doesn't linger on the unanswered list.

Comment: Please put the answer into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've answered your own question.  One point of clarification in that the way os.path.join() works is to strip out the preceding directories are tossed out (according to the Python docs related to os.path).  So the behavior you observed in invoking os.path.join() is consistent with how it is described.

One other thing to note: The get_filename() function invokes os.path.basename(), which will strip out any directory paths and return back only the basename.   So without an upload_to= parameter, there is no danger of this possibility.

However, if you override the ImageField() with your own upload_to function, this function will not be called and it may be better to invoke os.path.basename().  First, it will avoid saving the filename as the full directory path too.  I've found it therefore preferable to also invoke os.path.basename() within my upload_to function.  Has anyone else encoutnered this issue?

For more details, see: http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2010/08/try-me-out.html